# Need help in figuring out how to write dialogue as if my mouth was full (+18)

Tags: creative-writing, style, dialogue

I saw a similar question, but it didn't really have the answer I was seeking and it wasn't concerned with the same thing — sucking someone, thus the full mouth. I saw an answer there that suggests removing certain letters from words and replacing them with ', but that while perhaps a proper way to simulate what I'm going for, won't have the same effect. A friend suggested something along the lines — *"Shoo, dis nau gisme..."* for the sentence *"So, this now gives me..."* I like this more than *"So, 'his now 'ives"* like the answer I spoke of would have me write. It just doesn't feel the same.

So, is there anything I could use "study" this slang version of someone talking with a full mouth?

Comment: I think Amadeus' answer here makes the most sense: https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/39197/54131 You wouldn't get "dis" because d is just as unpronounceable as t/th when the mouth is obstructed. Just stick two fingers in your mouth and try. In fact, record yourself saying all the lines you want in your dialogue while you have two fingers in your mouth, and listen to how it affects speech.

Comment: OK, if somebody was offended by the original form of my comment they should have deleted it not change it to something else.

Comment: If you can make a sibilant such as in "shoo" while doing that, then you are either not very enthusiastic, or your partner deserves the nickname Mr. Peanut.

Comment: @BobaFit I chose to edit it rather than deleting it as I felt you were making a valid point about the example provided in the question, but that your suggestion to the OP (which I won't repeat) was inappropriate. I'll leave it in its present form as it was really the suggestion that tipped it over the line.

Comment: @F1Krazy  Yeah, editing isn't moderating.